# Using text for a link using XSL for an HTML Pop-up

Tags: html, css, xml, arcgis

I am making an HTML popup for ESRI ArcMap using a custom xsl template.  For my xsl file the code is working well except that instead of showing the full link to my documents/images in the popup I only want to show either a hyperlinked "text" or the file name (image.jpg or file.doc).

The code that links to internal documents/images is:

```
<xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., '\\')]">
<a href="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
</a>
</xsl:when>
```

It works great for images and pdf files, however, it does give me a window to Open or Save a file for word documents which is not really an issue but I prefer if it could be directly opened in a window. The goal is to have multiple links in different rows in the table in the pop-up and would like to have just one code for all links (that include images, .doc, and .pdf files).

The entire code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheetversion="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.o       rg/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
       <style type="text/css" media="screen">
             .align-left { float:left; margin: 0 15px 15px 0; }
             .align-right { float:right; margin: 0 0 15px 15px; }
       </style>
   </head>
  <body>
     <img src="C:\DATA\image.bmp" alt="Logo" class="align-left" />
     <img src="C:\DATA\image2.bmp" alt="Logo2" class="align-right" />
     <center style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 17px; color: black"><strong>TEXT</strong></center>
    <xsl:variable name="nameCol" select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field/FieldName"/>
    <body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#ffffff;"></body>
    <iframe width="300" height="0"></iframe>
    <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:14px;text-align:left;width:100%;border:1;padding:5px 5px 5px 5px">
    <tr bgcolor="#348017">        
    <xsl:if test="string-length($nameCol) != 0">
    <th width="50%" align="left">Field Name</th>
 </xsl:if>
   <th width="50%" align="left">Field Value</th>
 </tr>
  <xsl:variable name="index" select="1"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field">
 <tr>
    <xsl:if test="(position() +1) mod 2">
    <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#6CBB3C</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="string-length($nameCol) != 0">
 <td>
   <xsl:value-of select="FieldName"/>
 </td>
</xsl:if>
 <td>
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'www.')]">
    <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href">http://<xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
    </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
   </a>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'http:')]">
    <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
    </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
  </a>
</xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'https:')]">
  <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
  </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
 </a>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., '\\')]">
  <a href="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
  </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
 </a>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm new at HTML, CSS, and XSL but trying to learn so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking around I found a solution.

This code works the way I need it too, giving me a hyperlinked "Link" instead of the entire path.

```
<xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., '\\')]">
<a href="_blank">
<xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:text>Link</xsl:text>
</a>
</xsl:when>
```

One other question; my images/documents are on a server (//server/file) however I also have video that I might need to embed in the same table(this I have done already and it works) how would I make the code so it uses the

```
<a href="_blank" ></a>
```

tag for documents/images and use the

```
<embed src="_blank" ></embed>
```

tag for video.

Is it a change to the:

```
<xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., '\\')]">
```

to read the file type?

I would also appreciate suggestions for making my code better.

Thanks